# Android WebView YouTube not playing

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I've got an Android app that has a WebView that plays a remote web page. That page includes an embedded YouTube video. All works on phones I have tested - the page loads and the video plays. But one user on a SamSung instead gets a message to 'Please click here to watch this video on YouTube'. I figure that it has to do with some setting or software on her phone but I haven't been able to reproduce it, and I don't have access to that phone.

Anyone have any ideas on why it doesn't work on that phone.

[image: Click Here message screen shot]

Thanks,
Gary